# Scrapy - Code doesn't run Python 3.9 / 3.10

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Hello Stack Overflow Friends!

I'm trying to run a web scraper code at the terminal with Scrapy library, but its not working.

There's no error message, it starts and shut down after a couple seconds.

The code follows down below:

```
import os
import csv
import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector


with open('dataset__petz.csv', 'a+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = [
        "Link",
        "Title",
        "Images",
        "Reviews",
        "Average Stars",
        "Description",
        "Price",
    ]
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    total_pages = 7683 // 20
    for page_num in range(total_pages + 1):
        headers = {
            'authority': 'www.petz.com.br',
            'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"',
            'accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01',
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
            'referer': 'https://www.petz.com.br/cachorro',
            'accept-language': 'en-PK,en;q=0.9,ur-PK;q=0.8,ur;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5,sv;q=0.4,it;q=0.3',
            'cookie': '_ga=GA1.3.53852958.1643655176; ajs_anonymous_id=%226f300057-6c2b-4435-aeb2-64209b1c75ef%22; blueID=767f2efe-82e2-46a4-b53f-b0598a74e307; _scid=f9212b58-afba-46ab-9942-4aed2341831c; _pin_unauth=dWlkPVlXTm1PR1UxTVRrdE1XRmtOaTAwWW1JeUxUazNOak10WXpBd1pqSmpaRFExTXpnMw; _hjSessionUser_257734=eyJpZCI6IjE0YmJhZDZlLWE4ZmEtNWU4MS1hNjY2LTBhMjk5NDRmMDkyMCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDM2NTUxODY2MzgsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; JSESSIONID=097C5726F3743DB8DA56DEC9394CCAA5; petzCarrinho=true; _gid=GA1.3.1987275895.1645062208; _gat=1; ab.storage.sessionId.8160f757-f57f-4d17-9cfb-44c82d5e8f64=%7B%22g%22%3A%2256dad591-fbb9-58ca-b56f-16301eedcaa0%22%2C%22e%22%3A1645062242208%2C%22c%22%3A1645062210438%2C%22l%22%3A1645062212208%7D; _uetsid=03d15a308f9311ec8c0761ae408d793e; _uetvid=03887a2082c711ec88b9d507def7682c; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=0; _hjSession_257734=eyJpZCI6IjliY2Q3YWE1LTIyZWMtNGY1OS04MmM4LWViNzYwYmFiZjdlYSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDUwNjIyMTM3NTYsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; cto_bundle=OjK6yF9rYUQwazkzZ1hqbGQ0TVVhc1ZINEtqUkZrenI2cVJTRG5oRW1XWmZDc3JBOG9tZ1FEblFqYnh4VVZTTzhpTlBiSmU0cVdjWmo1SmI5NFBnY1pRVWNKT2htbUxqOHVnWGh4eld3OVdzRFBwcERJdVVkUzVTVkZ2Nm5XZyUyQmRtekNaM05kY3dwVENacUJmMSUyQjBXRnIlMkZnQnclM0QlM0Q; _clck=1jfl8ab|1|ez2|0; _clsk=yj3l8j|1645062215905|1|1|a.clarity.ms/collect; _sctr=1|1645038000000; AWSALB=F7AuR70LF27a5QDYcZ/a3VpvBix2n+zWGKxBvpe1n0V2Lu3LYXtzsAY9buKvrZ50OUucjSRaEdOD2kHurmAO9MZ7Q0jEnQqG3AD+XaW3H0fWTfODTk3SS2VrdZ37; AWSALBCORS=F7AuR70LF27a5QDYcZ/a3VpvBix2n+zWGKxBvpe1n0V2Lu3LYXtzsAY9buKvrZ50OUucjSRaEdOD2kHurmAO9MZ7Q0jEnQqG3AD+XaW3H0fWTfODTk3SS2VrdZ37',
        }

        params = (
            ('page', page_num),
            ('np', '385'),
            ('total', '7683'),
            ('view', ''),
            ('sort', '0'),
            ('cor', '0'),
            ('pi', ''),
            ('pf', ''),
        )

        r = requests.get('https://www.petz.com.br/cachorro', headers=headers, params=params)
        
        response = Selector(text=r.text)
        
        products = response.xpath('//li[@class="liProduct"]')
        if products == []:
            break
        for product in products[:2]:
            link = product.xpath('.//a[@id="produto-href"]/@href').get()
            product_request = requests.get(url=f'https://www.petz.com.br{link}', headers=headers)
            
            product_resp = Selector(text=product_request.text)
            product_images = product_resp.xpath('//div[@class="sp-wrap"]/a/@href').getall()
            
            data = {
                "Link": product_request.url,
                "Title": product_resp.xpath('normalize-space(//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text())').get(),
                "Images": ", ".join(product_images),
                "Reviews": product_resp.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@itemprop="reviewCount"]/text())').get(),
                "Average Stars": product_resp.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@itemprop="ratingValue"]/text())').get(),
                "Description": product_resp.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@itemprop="description"])').get(),
                "Price": product_resp.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="current-price-left"]/strong/text())').get(),
            }
            
            csv_writer.writerow(data)
            print(data)
            
            for image_link in product_images:
                image_resp = requests.get(image_link)
                with open(os.path.join("images", image_link.split('/')[-1]), 'wb') as image_downloader:
                    image_downloader.write(image_resp.content)

import pandas as pd
csv_file = pd.read_csv('dataset__petz.csv')
csv_file.to_excel('dataset__petz.xlsx', index=False)
```

Any ideas on why it could not be working?

[Here's a picture of my Pycharm console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEClm.png)

Comment: You `break` here: `if products == []: break`. That means if the first page doesn't produce products the program is done?

Comment: Marry me Timus, it's working. You and i can conquer the world

Comment: Glad I could help. Not sure about the marriage thing, though :)

Comment: Can you post your answer so i can upvote?